# Splitting algorithm in R--Tree

Tags: tree, r-tree

Is splitting algorithm affecting our query answer? There is several splitting algorithms for R-tree such as Quadratic, Linear, Greene's, Ang and Tan etc. Besides search time, does this algorithms affect our query answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R-trees always give *exact* answers. So how can the answer then be different?

That is, unless you have some implementation errors, of course.

In my experiences, the R*-tree splitting algorithm works best. Ang-and-Tan seems to be "linear", but pretty useless for real query scenarios.